# mean menu custom width call in jquery

Tags: navigation, responsive-design, nav

js
every thing works fine but i have a problem ... My website have two navigation on different pages can any one tell me how to call the **meanscreenWidth by custom.js** file i have used below code but no effect..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            if('meanScreenWidth: "480"'){
            jQuery('header .topFront nav').meanmenu();
            }

            else if{
                         ('meanScreenWidth: "767"'){
            jQuery('header nav').meanmenu();
                         }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: @Jefferson Don't correct typos in code blocks. You're fundamentally altering the question. That edit should **never** have been approved.

Comment: @meagar, actually the edit fixes a lot of grammatical errors and improves the text. I see now that where `mean` was actually correct, the edit changes it to `main`. It was kind of hard to spot it given that the title and parts of code says `mean menu` which seems quite wrong. I wish you would have reverted only the code block part instead of reverting all the fixes to the English as well. Anyway, this is a cooperative site. Sometimes we make mistakes. We'd do well not to fight and try to keep improving.

Comment: @Shahbaz Grammatical errors are a *distant* second priority to maintaining the integrity of the question's code.

Answer (score 0):

This is nonsensical:

```
if ('meanScreenWidth: "480"') {
```

That isn't how you query the screen's width, or *anythings* width. All you're doing is testing the trutyness of a static string, which will always be `true`.

If you want to get the width of the viewport with jQuery, you can use `$(window).width()`.

Comment: meanScreenWidth is predefined in meanmenu.js please check 
[it (out]www.meanthemes.com/plugins/meanmenu/)

Answer (score 0):

This code will work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('.navigation').meanmenu({
                meanScreenWidth: "767", 
        });            
     });
</script>
```